# Why does my navbar not expand when I click the button?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap site, and on mobile, when I press the button, the menu does not expand.

Code: http://pastebin.com/E6NZC9Zv

Answer (score 2):

I receive: `Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery` when running it in FireFox. Maybe you need to load jQuery before Bootstrap?

Comment: Thank you, changed the priority of script loading to: jQuery then Bootstrap.JS and it worked.